# Image Linear Transformation graph interpretation

Tags: image, image-processing, image-compression

While revesing some image processing material, I was faced to some grahs which I can't understand.

How should I interpret these graphs?

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are pixel value transformations. `I(x,y)` is the pixel value of the input image, `O(x,y)` is the mapped value. With the first one, you get an inverted image. The the second one is a piscewise transformation where it clips the values below `I1` and above `I2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphs simply plot the function that describes a gray value transformation in image processing.
Looking at a graph is more intuitive than looking at a formula. Like in other disciplines, function graphs are just a quick and convenient way to discuss what's going on.

It shows two very simple examples.

The first one inverts the image.

`O(x,y)` or better `O(I(x,y)) = 255 - I(x,y)`

The second example clips anything below I1 and above I2 and normalizes the interval [I1,I2] to [0,255].

```
O(I(x,y)) =
```

- `0`,  if I(x,y) < I1
- `255`, if I(x,y) > I2
- `(I(x,y) - I1) * 255/(I2-I1)`, else

Of course these graphs gain value with more complex or even non-linear tranformations.